# How to hide detail indicator in detail grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having an issue trying to hide the detail indicator when my row has a group level of 0.

Here is part of the code where I have the row changing color and where I think that I should be able to hide the detail indicator...

```
    dataBound: function (e) {
        var data = this.dataSource.data();
        $.each(data, function (i, row) {
            if (row.get("globalGroupLevel") == 0) {
                var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ');
                element.addClass("colored-row");

                // 4rth attempt
                //this.collapseRow(this.tbody.find(">tr.k-master-row"));
                //element.collapseRow(this.tbody.find(">tr.k-master-row"));

                // 3rd attempt
                //this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row>.k-hierarchy-cell>a").hide();

                // 1rst attempt
                //element.removeClass("td.k-hierarchy-cell .k-icon");

                // 2nd attempt
                //var masterRow = this;//.element.closest("tr.k-detail-row").prev();
                //$("#CatalogGrid").data("kendoGrid").collapseRow(masterRow);
                //masterRow.find("td.k-hierarchy-cell .k-icon").removeClass();
            }
        });
    }
```

as you can see where I have my attempts commented out and what I have tried.
So you can see that my rows turn blue when the globalGroupLevel is equal to 0, and this is when the detail indicator should not be there...

here is a screenshot of what it normally looks like

[image: Screen A]

and here's what it looks like when I made my attempts

[image: Screen B]

and this is how I am trying to get it to look

[image: Screen C]

Any idea's? and just to reiterate, the detail indicator needs to be hidden when globalGroupLevel is = 0

Comment: Is the detail table loaded in the page and just collapsed? Or do you retrieve detail table after icon click through ajax? Just asking because if you use second option, you will not probably able to do it.

Comment: The detail table gets loaded when you click on the detail indicator

Answer (score 0):

Try something like in your dataBound :

```
dataBound: function() {
    var dataSource = this.dataSource;         
    this.element.find('tr.k-master-row').each(function() {
       var row = $(this);            
       var data = dataSource.getByUid(row.data('uid'));
                // this example will work if ReportId is null or 0 (if the row has no details)
       if (!data.get('globalGroupLevel')) {
         row.find('.k-hierarchy-cell a').css({ opacity: 0.3, cursor: 'default' }).click(function(e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); return false; });
       }
    });
}
```

Hope this help

EDIT: For convinience I did an example hiding all Detai indicators 
now you just have to do your validations to hide.

http://dojo.telerik.com/ALeNa

Comment: I tried implementing that into my code and to no avail